# current user login details

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to get current user login details using c# code for sharepoint site.

please reply with codings.

thanks in advance...

Comment: I'll get right on that for you ... Anything else you need?

Answer (score 2):

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser

thats all you need to do.
I guess its already too late for this answer